# ¿Como puedo usar el algoritmo de encriptacion SHA512 en angular?

Tags: webservice, typescript, angular4, component

Quiero encriptar cierta información a la hora de enviarla a un `web service`, pero no encuentro ninguna respuesta clara a como usar la libreria `SHA512` en angular.

¿Como la uso desde `angular`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza `CryptoJS`, te permite encriptar en muchas formas (incluida SHA512) de manera fácil.

Lo instalas y usas de la siguiente forma:

```
npm install crypto-js

import * as crypto from 'crypto-js'; 

console.log(crypto.SHA512("string a encriptar").toString());
```

> Documentación Oficial: [Aquí](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, exactamente lo que necesitaba!